# Holomorphic extension on the closed disk of a bounded holomorphic function defined on the open disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f :D(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a **holomorphic** and **bounded** function on the unit open disk $D(0,1)$. A friend of mine wondered whether we could always find a continuous extension on the closed disk $\bar{D}(0,1)$. This seems reasonable intuitively, but I think there might be exceptions. After doing a few research on the topic, I ended up finding information about Blaschke products and Hardy spaces. But I don't have enough knowledge on complex analysis yet to understand easily such concepts. Therefore is there a simple approach, or a counter-example to this problem? This question is purely out of curiosity, any answers or references will be gladly welcomed.

Comment: What does it mean to be holomorphic on a closed set? Usually, holomorphic is defined to be a property of functions on open sets.

Comment: Oops! Thanks, my bad. I edited, thank you.

Comment: You can think about approaching it from the opposite point of view, start with a bounded discontinuous function on the boundary, and solve the Dirichlet problem for the unique harmonic function on the interior. This together with the Harmonic conjugate will give you a holomorphic function which is discontinuous when extended to the closed disk but still bounded. The Poisson kernel is what you need.

Comment: $e^{\frac{z+1}{z-1}}$ is a simple counterexample of a bounded holomorphic function on the unit disc that has a (bad) discontinuity at $1$, though it can be continued at all other circle points and it has absolute value $1$ there; more generally for any positive singular measure zero $\mu$ on the circle of mass one (singular meaning its support has Lebesgue measure zero on the circle), the corresponding $f(z)=\exp(\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac{z+e^{i\theta}}{z-e^{i\theta}}}d\mu(\theta))$ is a similar example, with the unit mass point at $1$ corresponding to the above